# Delete Embedded Document from ListfField in Mongo Engine

Tags: python, mongoengine, nosql

I haven't found a clear answer to this yet, but the issue is I need to delete and/or update an Embedded Document in a listfield.  So if I had a schema:

```
-Team
    -Players
        -name
        -number
```

how would I delete or update Players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this (note these are raw mongodb queries):

```
# To update the number:
db.team.update({ "name": "FC Barcelona", "players.name" : "Lionel Messi" }, { $set: { "players.$.number" : 11 }})

# To remove the player from the list:
db.team.update({ "name": "FC Barcelona", "players.name" : "Cesc Fabregas" }, { $pull: { "players.name" : "Cesc Fabregas" }})
```